# Putting rows as a single column in r

Tags: r, reshape

I have the following data.frame **x**

```
a d g
b e h
c f i
```

**Note**: letters are used as an example. The actual data.frame has numbers in place of letters (real data which are not in ascending order, as in this example)

I want to transform it in an unique column, by putting columns from 2 to 4 under the first. The expected result is the following

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
```

I tried the following code

```
matrix(t(x), ncol=1, nrow=ncol(x)*nrow(x), byrow=F)
```

but it gives (obviously) the following

```
a
d 
g
b
e
h
c
f
i
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
X <- matrix(letters[1:9], ncol=3)
matrix(X, ncol=1)
```

R matrices are in [column major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-major_order), so you can easily concatenate them into a single column vector with the `matrix` function.

Comment: I used letters as an example. They can be any number.

Comment: Right, I was just trying to replicate your example. Does my answer do what you need?

Comment: It does. That was quite easy, indeed. And very useful. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for sharing! took me a while to find this as usually the stack option is suggested which I can't make working

Answer (score 3):

I find `stack` also very useful

```
X <- data.frame(matrix(letters[1:9], ncol=3),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
stack(X)[,"values",drop=FALSE]
```

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I am not able to make your example working

Comment: I have now cleared my workspace and recomputed the two lines. It gives the desired output `"a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "f"  "g"  "h"  "i"`. What is the problem on your machine? Wrong order?

Comment: `Error in stack.data.frame(X) : no vector columns were selected`

Comment: Use `X <- data.frame(matrix(letters[1:9], ncol=3),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`. I have that always turned off by using `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` in one of the very first lines of my scripts. (I hate it when characters are turned into factors by default.)